# how to make a query in SQL from the result of another avg(query)

Tags: sql, average, multiple-tables

I wonder if someone could help with this please, I'm new at SQL and I am trying to do this.

I have the following 3 tables/columns

```
Bookings(roomID,bookingID,guestID) 
Room(rooCost,roomID) 
Guests(name,lname ext)
```

I guess we can leave Guest table alone for this task.
So in essence I would need to extract the avg(roomID) and how much this particular room costs from a different table/column combination.

Please forgive my pseudo code bellow :)

Now, I'd like to know the

```
    avg room(Booking.roomID) rented by all guests and its related cost(Room.roomCost)
```

So I guess something like:

```
query the avg(booking.roomID) (btw this would give me an int 10)
then
query the cost of room(10) from Room.roomCost
```

I have try so many combinations!, it's unbelievable!! Once I was nearly there I think, but I was getting like +400 lines response from a 20 line table.??

Appreciated any help.
Many thanks

Comment: can you show some sample data and your desired result? Avg of room id makes absolutely no sense..

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result as tabular text

Comment: Why do you want the average room ID?  That doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Yes, a sample of the data and desired output would be good.  I get what you want regarding average.  There's confusion because you say you want to average Room ID, which is probably not what you meant to say.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you all.
Sorry I'll try to be more clear.

My fictitious hotel has 20 rooms in total. 
So I have a table 'Booking'  and something like round(avg(roomID)) would return, on average, the most booked Room,  in this case would be Room #10.

Now, all I need is the price for Room(#10) and that data(price) is but in a different table, called 'Room', column roomCost with a int value representing the cost of every room in this case 40.

Once I have my a avg best selling/booked room I would need to extract its cost, ultimately returning something like:

roomID 10 roomCost 40.

Comment: sorry I promise I'll learn how to post more lean tidy post :/  pretty shocking lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get room wise average cost you can have with below query:

```
select roomid, avg(roocost) from room
group by roomid
```

If you want to have the average value of rooms rented by any guest then use below query:

```
select roomid, avg(roocost) from room
where roomid in (select roomid from bookings)
group by roomid
```

To calculate guest wise room wise average cost:

```
   select guestid,roomid, avg(roocost) from room r inner join booking b
   on r.roomid=b.roomid
   group by guestid,roomid
```

To calculate guest wise room wise average cost (withe guest name):

```
   select name guestname,guestid,roomid, avg(roocost) from room r inner join booking b
   on r.roomid=b.roomid
   inner join guests g on g.guestid=b.guestid 
   group by name,guestid,roomid
```